# Why non-exhaustive patterns warning, when using Bool and Finite 2?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I'm hoping to define an instance of a new class, for `Bool`, without creating partial functions, via `Finite 2`, but it isn't working.

My code:

```
-- SO test case, re: my HasFin instance for Bool.
--
-- David Banas <capn.freako@gmail.com>
-- February 9, 2018

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Bogus.BoolHasFin where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Finite
import Data.Finite.Internal (Finite(..))

class KnownNat (Card a) => HasFin a where
  type Card a :: Nat
  toFin :: a -> Finite (Card a)
  unFin :: Finite (Card a) -> a

instance HasFin Bool where
  type Card Bool = 2

  toFin False = finite 0
  toFin True  = finite 1

  unFin = \case
    Finite 0 -> False
    Finite 1 -> True
```

And the GHC compilation results:

```
Davids-Air-2:test dbanas$ stack ghc -- -c so_BoolHasFin.hs 

so_BoolHasFin.hs:30:11: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In a case alternative:
        Patterns not matched: (Finite p) where p is not one of {1, 0}
```

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this warning?
It seems like, having bounded the argument to `unFin`, via `Finite 2`, ought to have been sufficient.

Added on 2018-02-10:

As per a suggestion made privately by Conal, this code:

```
unFin (Finite 0) = False
unFin _          = True
```

eliminates the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's at least in part because there's nothing in the definition of `Finite` that restricts the contained `Integer` to be within the assumed bounds (`0` to `n-1`): `newtype Finite (n :: Nat) = Finite Integer`.